# Classic experience buttons in lightning

Tags: lightning-experience, custom-button, page-layout

We are migrating to lightning and are noticing that some classic custom buttons work in lightning as long as they're not javascript. We have a bunch of custom buttons that replace(think of having the standard new button and custom new button) and override(standard override of a standard action/button) in our org. We also have some standard buttons that can't be overwritten with a lightning component(Quote new button).

This is fine, but as we rework these into lightning components we are running into the dilemma that these classic buttons still live on the related lists in lightning. We don't want users accidentally clicking these classic custom buttons. We know we can remove these and add new ones from the page layouts, however, we want to support classic and lightning together temporarily. If we take them off the page layouts or add duplicate named ones with different functionality it will confuse users.

We would ideally like to duplicate our layouts temporarily and have 1 layout for classic and 1 layout for lightning just for these custom buttons. But there doesn't seem to be a way to configure salesforce to serve specific layouts based on the experience.

[I've looked at similar issues that deal with record level buttons](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244218/hide-custom-buttons-in-lightning-but-not-in-classic), but this issue is more around related list buttons.

Has anyone else experienced this issue and worked around it?

Examples:

The new button for quote can't be overridden for lightning experience. Currently it is overridden for classic. We made a quick action that performs the same functionality, but this button still exists on the page layout and serves the standard object creation form. We can't remove this from the page layout since it's used in classic.

[image]

The new button on this button was duplicated to replace standard functionality on related lists. We want to override the standard new button with a lightning component, but we would have to add the standard new button to the page layouts. There would be 2 new buttons in lightning which is problematic.
[image]

Comment: I'm thinking my only option is to convert the duplicate reseller new button into the overridden standard new button. As for the quote new button, I'm just stuck with have the new button on the related list. We'll just make users aware of that until we disable classic

Comment: Why not you can create one component for quote related list without action?